# App bar is not full screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know what to do(
Why does it look thhis way? The width is match_parent. How can I remove the padings?

[MainActivity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTC7y.jpg)

However, toolber.xml looks the way I want it to look
[toolbar.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgn2W.jpg)

Toolber.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.design3.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"

        layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these from RelativeLayout:

```
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Layout like..Remove all padding from your Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.design3.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"

        layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity.xml has padding properties. They apply to all layouts children. One of them is your toolbar. Try removing paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingLeft from MainActivity.xml